Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'ApiResponse<Map<String, dynamic>>
I am working on a flutter app that calls an API to get all the servers from the backend. My backend is in the Laravel.
When I run the API in postman it gives me the correct result, but when I call the API in app it fetch the result but did not display in list on screen.!This is the error I am getting on running the APP](https://i.sstatic.net/7C5rlUeK.png)
Belwo is the code where the error is occuring in terminal on running the app.


I have tried to json decode the data, but it did not work.
I have also commented these code and then run the app, then the API call is not working.

You should paste your code here instead of posting pictures

This usually means that your data is a null value and you need to print to see the value of data

Ensure you're using await with the asynchronous operation to guarantee the data is available before accessing it:
Future<ApiResponse<App<String, dynamic>>> fetchData() async {
  // ... fetch data from API
}

void handleData() async {
  ApiResponse<App<String, dynamic>> apiResponse = await fetchData();
  App<String, dynamic> appData = apiResponse.data;
  // Use the appData here
}


Also i recomend to use Dio or Retrofit to call API's


I have used async and await to fetch the data.

Try using null safety type by replace
ApiResponse<App<String, dynamic>> to ApiResponse<App<String, dynamic>>?
and modify check condition by
if (resp?.success ?? false) {

}


If I modify the condition, it gives me the error while returning the data.
